# Rejecting from Promise.all

Tags: reactjs, async-await, es6-promise, promise.all

I have an aysnc function that fetches data and returns the value of `Promise.all` i.e.

```
const fetchDownloadMenuData = async selectedItems => {
return Promise.all(
  selectedItems.map(async item => {
    try {
      if (item.id === 'interviewGuide') {
        const interviewGuide = await positionCandidatesService.getCandidate(
          positionId,
          candidateSelected.id
        );
        return interviewGuide.interviewGuide;
      }

      if (item.id !== 'overview' && item.id !== 'profile') {
        const outcome = await outcomesService.get(candidateSelected.id, item.id);
        return outcome;
      }
      return null;
    } catch (err) {
      appInsights.trackException({
        error: new Error(`Error fetching candidate outcome: ${JSON.stringify(err)}`)
      });
      return null;
    }
  })
  )};
```

I call this function like this:

```
 try {
  downloadData = await fetchDownloadMenuData(selectedItems);
} catch (err) {
  appInsights.trackException({
    error: new Error(`Could not fetch all PDF data: ${JSON.stringify(err)}`)
  });
  return;
}
```

But it never goes into the catch. Why is this? How do i get it to reject if all the promises don't resolve?

Thanks

Comment: I believe in your catch, you should reject the Promise like so:
```Promise.reject()```
Otherwise it will resolve it

Answer (score 0):

You're not rejecting in the `map...catch block`, instead you're returning the `null`. That's why `Promise.all` not able to catch the exception. You need use `throw` in the catch block, Remember, `throw` will terminate the execution flow.

Try like this

```
selectedItems.map(async item => {
    try {
       ...async stuff
    } catch (err) {
      appInsights.trackException({
        error: new Error(`Error fetching candidate outcome: ${JSON.stringify(err)}`)
      });
      throw err OR throw new Error(err) <-- this is missing earlier.
    }
  })
```